# Shunt resistor and reverse current

Tags: arduino, current-measurement

I am planning to add a 50A current sensing shunt resistor to my project. I want to use the ADS1110 ADC+amplifier IC to measure the tiny voltage drop. 
The problem is that the current can range from 40A to -15A , and I also want to measure the negative current. How should I proceed?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxJQGo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the schematic the "load that can be a generator" is a motor with a regenerative braking system. sometimes it is a load, sometimes it charges the battery.

Comment: Could you maybe add a quick schematic of the setup, so everyone is on the same page?

Comment: According to the datasheet the ADS1110 can measure a negative voltage.

Comment: +1 to @JorenVaes' response. Put a diagram showing bus voltage, sensing resistor placement (i.e. high- or low-side) and other details.

Comment: added schematic

Comment: I saw that 'negative voltage' thing, but I am not sure reversed current will mean negative voltage ...

Comment: If you're planning to measure negative **DC** currents then your configuration does not let you to do so, because one end of the sensing resistor is tied to GND. You must go for high-side sensing with high common-mode voltage support. INA240 can be a good choice but it does not contain an ADC. Another option would be using an external opamp (with dual supply) to shift the output from 0-Vs range to -Va/+Va range (See Fig.9 on Pg.15 of datasheet).

Comment: yes that is DC current.

Comment: Refer to my last updated comment.

Comment: @RohatKılıç There will still be a voltage across the resistor in his diagram if the load is charging the voltage source. The current to charge the battery *has* to come from somewhere.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Hmm yes, you are right. I missed that "Can be a generator" statement.